# sort() method for collection no longer works

Tags: javascript, spotify

The sort() method referenced here https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-collection.html does not seem to work anymore since a couple of week.

```
var sorted = playlist.tracks.sort('duration', 'asc');
```

It used to work perfectly, but now when I use it it does not return.

Anyone aware of a change ?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this isn't working properly. The function's done callback isn't called as would be the case if the request was successful. Instead, the fail callback is called. I'm going to write a bug report for it and let the people closest to the code take a look at it. On a side note, I'd like to mention Spotify no longer accepts new apps to its platform. Playlist manipulation is also possible to do using the [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api). Any reason you're not using it?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation. Strangely, it was working before properly that's why I'm confused. 

The project I'm working on is [an Alfred workflow](https://github.com/vdesabou/alfred-spotify-mini-player). I call my app with applescript and the app returns results via web sockets. This is perfect for me compared to Web API:
-No OAuth required, which is complicated because it is not service based, so I don't have any server, so it would require the user to login very frequently.
-I can control Spotify (launch playlist, star tracks, add tracks to playlist very easily)